# mongoose query for hour range with counter filed

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, hour

This is the schema:

```
var LogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    EventId:        { type: String, required: [true, "EventId can't be empty"]},
    Computer:       { type: String, required: [true, "Computer can't be empty"] },
    TimeCreated:    { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    IpAddress:      { type: String },
    FailureReason:  { type: String },
    TargetUserName: { type: String },
    SubjectUserName:{ type: String },

    moreInfo:       [{ type: String}],
})
```

I need a query that pop all the rows that:
 'TimeCreated' > 10PM and 'TimeCreated' < 6AM

In addition the query checks the 'EventId' by $or, this is the query:

```
    rulesMap :{
            eventId : [6416,4159],
            period: [config.hours._10_PM, config.hours._6_AM],
            maximum: 10,
            onlyFailed: false,
        }    
    var query = {
                $or: [],
                $and:[]
            };
            rulesMap.eventId.forEach(function (eventId) {
                query.$or.push({'EventId':eventId});
            });
            query.$and.push({'TimeCreated':{$gt: rulesMap.period[0], $lt: rulesMap.period[1]}});

logSchema.find(query).exec(function (err, logs) {
                    callback(err, logs)
                })
```

and i need to alert if the number of result is more that the rulesMap.maximum.

**the query with the $and doesn't work for me and the result is always empty.**

Comment: What are the values for `config.hours._10_PM` and `config.hours._6_AM`?

Comment: `config.hours._6_AM = 6;`
`config.hours._10_PM = 22;`

Comment: The result is empty because `TimeCreated` is a `Date` timestamp so your query will not match any documents that have `TimeCreated > 22` & `TimeCreated < 6` hrs. Unless you have another field that only holds the hour and use that field within your query, the above will not work.

Comment: ok, i didn't have anther field that hold only the hour, but with aggregate function i can do  `{"$project":"hour":{"$hour":"$TimeCreated"}} ` , and then with  `{"$match":{"hour":{"$gte":22,"$lte":6}}}`. but for that i need to group the result by i need the array of each log so i can't use group.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47887357/mongoose-query-for-hour-range-with-counter-filed/47893996#comment82751794_47887357), you would need to use the aggregation framework for the above query. Your pipeline will comprise of a **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/)** and **[`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/)** stages.

The initial **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/)** step will hold the first query with the `eventId` array values. The second pipeline step will then make use of the **[`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/)** operator to query the documents using the $hour operator on the TimeCreated field without having an extra **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)** pipeline.

The following aggregate operation shows the above concept:

```
const rulesMap = {
    eventId : [6416,4159],
    period: [config.hours._10_PM, config.hours._6_AM],
    maximum: 10,
    onlyFailed: false,
}; 

const match = { 
    "$match": { 
        "EventId": { 
            "$in": rulesMap.eventId 
         } 
     } 
};

const redact = {
    "$redact": {
        "$cond": [
            { 
                "$and": [  
                    { "$lt": [ { "$hour": "$TimeCreated" }, 6 ] },
                    { "$gt": [ { "$hour": "$TimeCreated" }, 22 ] }
                ]
            },
            "$$KEEP",
            "$$PRUNE"
        ]
    }    
}

logSchema.aggregate([match, redact]).exec(callback)
```